# How to test whether class B is derived from template family of classes

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits, c++03

How to test at compile time whether class B is derived from std::vector?

```
template<class A>
struct is_derived_from_vector {
  static const bool value = ????;
};
```

How to test at compile time whether class B is derived from template family?

```
template<class A, template< class > class Family>
struct is_derived_from_template {
  static const bool value = ????;
};
```

Using:

```
template<class T> struct X {};

struct A : X<int> {}
struct B : std::vector<char> {}
struct D : X<D> {}

int main() {
   std::cout << is_derived_from_template<A, X>::value << std::endl; // true
   std::cout << is_derived_from_template<D, X>::value << std::endl; // true
   std::cout << is_derived_from_vector<A>::value << std::endl; // false
   std::cout << is_derived_from_vector<B>::value << std::endl; // true
}
```

Comment: With template metaprogramming, it is important to make it explicit whether you need a C++03 only or a C++11 solution is good (although I am not sure that C++11 can help here). And as a smart remark, given that you should never inherit from standard containers the original trait is simple: `false` :P

Comment: C++03. I use msvc 2010 compiler. Therefore I agree to use `decltype` in addition. `std::vector` is for example ony. If you do not know C++03 solution then C++11 solution is welcome also.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, template <typename> class Tmpl>  // #1 see note
struct is_derived
{
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    static no & test(...);

    template <typename U>
    static yes & test(Tmpl<U> const &);

    static bool const value = sizeof(test(std::declval<T>())) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> struct X {};

struct A : X<int> {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_derived<A, X>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_derived<int, X>::value << std::endl;
}
```

*Note:* In the line marked `#1`, you could also make your trait accept *any* template that has at least one, but possibly more type arguments by writint:

```
template <typename, typename...> class Tmpl
```

Comment: If you use `template<typename...>class Tmpl` and use a parameter pack for your test function, you should also be able to handle a template with any number of arguments, not just one.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it will work only for templates with a single argument. Even if you augment it to take the *usual* two arguments of `std::vector` the implementation is allowed to add extra template parameters (as long as it provides default values for those parameters), so it will not be 100% portable

Comment: @Oktalist: Could you please post a counterexample? I have an idea how I might fix this if the problem does indeed exist.

Comment: My mistake. §14.8.2.1(4) contains the special rule which allows template argument deduction to deduce a _simple-template-id_ which is a base class of the argument type. No such rule for user-defined conversions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation that I needed to know if a class is derived from a vector(like)-class. Unfortunately there is no C++-11 or variadic macros allowed in my project. So my solution was a mixture of [Kerrek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12182195/2056545) and this [article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mxc++-item-4.htm) with some googletest-code at the end:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class is_derived_from_vector
{
    typedef char Yes_t[1];
    typedef char No_t[2];

    static No_t& test(const void* const);

    template <typename U>
    static Yes_t& test(const std::vector<U>* const);

public:
    static const bool value = ((sizeof(test(static_cast<T*>(0)))) == (sizeof(Yes_t)));
};

template<class T> struct X {};
struct A : X<int> {};
struct B : std::vector<char> {};

TEST(Example, IsDerivedFrom)
{
   EXPECT_FALSE(is_derived_from_vector<A>::value);
   EXPECT_TRUE(is_derived_from_vector<B>::value);
}
```

A common solution for any templates I think would not be possible to define without usage of C++-11 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to this problem not long ago and after consulting with

> Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied

I was able to build the following which is more or less similar to what was provided in the comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, template <typename...> class U>
struct is_derived
{
private:
    template <typename...Ts>
    static constexpr std::true_type check(const U<Ts...>&);
    static constexpr std::false_type check(...);


    template <typename>
    struct is_same
    {
        static constexpr bool value = false;
    };

    template <typename...Ts>
    struct is_same <U<Ts...>>
    {
        static constexpr bool value = true;
    };

  public:
    static constexpr bool value =
        std::is_same<decltype(check(std::declval<T>())),
                     std::true_type>::value &&
        !is_same<T>::value;
};

template <typename, typename>
struct X
{
};

template <typename T>
struct Y : X <T, int>
{
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_derived<Y<int>, X>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_derived<X<int,int>, X>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_derived<int, X>::value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```