# &* for raw pointer, iterator and ... std::nullptr_t

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, nullptr

I have a template function that is enabled (through a std::enable_if) its parameter is a raw pointer, or has a std::iterator category or is a std::nullptr_t. In that function, a raw pointer (a data member) is set equal to the parameter, like that :

```
template<class T> void myFunction(T it) 
{
    _ptr = &*it;
}
```

The &* works well for pointer and iterator ... but it fails for a std::nullptr_t. Is there any solution available to avoid to write 2 different functions ?

Thank you.

Comment: Even `&*it` will not work if the type of `*it` has overloaded `operator&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest thing is to change the function to have two overloads, one for raw pointers/`nullptr_t` that just stores the value and one selected by SFINAE for iterators with your current implementation, although you should note that this will fail under some circumstances (in particular if `iterator::value_type` overloads unary `operator&`).

Answer (score 2):

As always, we can solve this with a *trait*. This time, let's not write a full class, since a simple function overload suffices.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
T get_addr(T t) { return std::addressof(*t); } // #1

std::nullptr_t get_addr(std::nullptr_t np) { return np; }
```

Usage:

```
T _ptr = get_addr(it);
```

(This trait also works if the type pointed to by `T` overloads `operator&`.)

You're invited to guard the overload `#1` with the same `enable_if` condition that you have in your main template.

Comment: "As always, a trait - this time" <- what that's supposed to me , sorry couldn't understand

Comment: You are better off also making a special case of pointers, to prevent dereferencing pointers that do not point to valid stuff. `template <typename T> T* get_addr(T* t) { return t;}`

Comment: @nightcracker: I'm assuming the OP is only going to use this inside the enable-if'ed function. Otherwise you're right of course.

Comment: @KerrekSB: you never know. Could it hurt to add it? I can do it if you don't mind.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Normally I'd make trait *classes* with static member functions. This time, though, an overloaded function works just fine.

Comment: @nightcracker: The OP also wants to use this for iterators, so no, let's not. He's advised to use his own `enable_if` restriction on the templated overload, though!

Comment: @KerrekSB but again if you'll write trait classes, you'll have to specialize for `std::nullptr_t` which is mostly same as overloaded functions even more, isn't it? Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: That's right, which is why I prefer a function overload set in this situation, rather than a set of class template specializations.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Here's [an example of a trait](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12182195/596781) that really needs to be a *class* template :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB That's usage of sfinae , I don't see any traits involved, are there? . Thanks for link though :)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: The entire thing is a trait that tests whether something is derived from a template class... "trait" is a quite general concept about extracting specific information about a generic parameter.