# C++ State Machin design : singleton or not

Tags: c++, reference, singleton, smart-pointers, state-machine

Yeah I know, the question of singleton's pattern has been discussed many times. Mine is slightly different, please read.

I'm working on a state machine. Any entity can hold a state machine dealing with states for according entities :

```
template <class T>
class State {
    // Default interface for a state
}

class Entity;
class SomeState : public State<Entity> {
    // Some implementation dedicated to Entity's type.
    // Presumably a Singleton but maybe I'm wrong
}

template <class T>
class StateMachine {
public:
    StateMachine(T& entity, SOME_TYPE initial_state);
private:
    T& m_entity;
}

class Entity {
public:
    // An entity that holds a state machine
    Entity(): m_stateMachine(*this, SOME_WAY_TO_GET_"SOME_TYPE") {}
private:
    // Its state machine
    StateMachine<Entity> m_stateMachine;
}
```

So my issue is :
What type should be "SOME_TYPE" ?

- I want to be able to store SOME_TYPE in containers (so a simple reference is not possible); maybe a reference_wrapper ? The reference or reference_wrapper appears to be the best solution to me because a state machine need to have a state (no null possible if it is a pointer).
- Same for smart_pointers : I tried with no success because the SomeState's constructor should be public using std::make_shared (maybe I should create it without std::make_shared ?)
- I don't want to use raw pointers (I don't want any "new" in my code)
- I want my StateMachine design to be able to run fast with a lot of entities and a lot of StateMachine + a state object shouldn't hold any state : that's why I don't really want to instantiate a state per entity and use a singleton instead, but maybe I'm wrong ?
- Because it's a State Machine (so I don't know which state I'm in) I can't use static methods instead of and object (singleton or not).

So, any idea ? How should I design it ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't completely understand what you're trying to do. Shouldn't the StateMachine have a whole set of states and not just a single `Entity`? And in your example code, `SomeState` somehow uses an `Entity`, which itself holds a `StateMachine`, are you trying to model hierarchical state machines that way?

Comment: A StateMachine holds the current State the Entity is in, just one State. And a StateMachine is associated to only one Entity. (There is a 0-1 relation between Entity and Statemachine since some Entiy(s) may not use a StateMachine, even if I only gave an example with a class of Entity for which each instance holds a distinct StateMachine).

Comment: The principle of creating the StateMachine class is so the code is factored in a component independant from the differents kinds of Entities that could use States to describe their behaviors.

Comment: If  every state machine only has a single state, then why does it need an `initial_state` argument? The initial state can only be the single state the state machine has.

Comment: the state may change during the life of the StateMachine and its Entity. But at one point there is only one State hold.

Comment: How can you change the state of the state machine? Nothing uses  `SomeState` (or any other instance of a class inheriting from `State`). To me it seems that changing the state requires creating a new instance of `StateMachine`.

Comment: It's the principle of a StateMachine. A StateMachine has a method "changeState" that call "exit" on the current state, change the state for the new one, and call "enter" on the new state.

Comment: I think I'm slowly getting how you're modeling the state machine. In your question you say that a state class itself doesn't have any mutable data members and that you don't want to create new instances every time the state changes because of that. I'd probably go with an additional caching state factory and an `enum` so that you can ask the factory to hand you a reference to a state based on the enumerator you pass to the factory. That way states are only instantiated the first time they're used similar to a signleton, but for testing you can provide a state factory that hands out mocks.

Comment: The way State is changed is not an issue, there is no need for a factory and an enum. Let me explain you why : a state contains 3 main methods : enter, execute, exit. Each frame of the simulation the StateMachine of each Entity is executed. Doing so the State hold by each StateMachine is executed through this "execute" method. But this method, which take a reference to the related Entity as a parameter, may change the state of the Entity calling something like `entity.stateMachine().changeState(OtherState::instance())`.

Comment: I tried many things but I think I finaly decided to go for a shared_ptr instantiated with `std::shared_ptr<SomeState>(new SomeState)` instead of `std::make_shared<SomeState>()`. It allow StateMachines to hold a null State but I can accept that since it's like having a "DoNothingState". Because of the template I have had an other issue (`shared_ptr<SomeState>` is not derived from `shared_ptr<State<Entity>>`, even if `SomeState` is a public `State<Entity>`), was tricky : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815038/why-cant-shared-ptr-resolve-inheritance-relationships-in-function-interface