# Trait to check if some specialization of template class is base class of specific class

Tags: c++, c++11, traits, c++14, type-traits

There is `std::is_base_of` in modern STL. It allow us to determine whether the second parameter is derived from first parameter or if they are the same classes both or, otherwise, to determine is there no such relation between them.

Is it possible to determine whether the one class is derived from some concrete template class without distinction of which concrete actual parameters involved to its specialization?

Say, we have;

```
template< typename ...types >
struct B {};
```

And

```
template< typename ...types >
struct D : B< types... > {};
```

Is it possible to define a type trait:

```
template< typename T > is_derived_from_B;
```

Such that it is derived from `std::true_type` when `T` is any specialization of `D` and derived from `std::false_type` if `T` is not derived from any specialization of `B`?

Comment: @Nim How to use it? Does it have any sufficient differences from the standard `std::is_base_of` type trait?

Comment: sorry, just understood your question after the reformatting, ignore the boost part of the comment..

Comment: I think something like `template< typename ...types > constexpr std::true_type helper(B< types... > const &); template< typename T > constexpr std::false_type helper(T &&); decltype(helper(std::declval< D const & >()))` is possible, if such overloading permitted.

Comment: @Orient No, `T&&` is an exact match and so is always preferred by overload resolution compared to the derived-to-base conversion.

Comment: @Orient You could do that with pointers: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d0d5ea3d60ec5e2 But it only works for accessible base classes.

Comment: @dyp Could you provide your own version of answer? The primacy belongs to you.

Comment: You can accept Piotr's answer if you like it. His initial version was cleaner than my initial version. Don't care about the rep.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test whether class B is derived from template family of classes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12181885/1639256)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you can assume that a derived type uses a public inheritance from `B<Args...>` (and so the upcasting is possible), then you can use the following SFINAE:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename Derived>
    struct is_derived_from_B
    {
        using U = typename std::remove_cv<
                                  typename std::remove_reference<Derived>::type
                                >::type;

        template <typename... Args>
        static auto test(B<Args...>*)
            -> typename std::integral_constant<bool
                                           , !std::is_same<U, B<Args...>>::value>;

        static std::false_type test(void*);

        using type = decltype(test(std::declval<U*>()));
    };
}

template <typename Derived>
using is_derived_from_B = typename detail::is_derived_from_B<Derived>::type;
```

*Tests:*

```
static_assert(is_derived_from_B<const D<int, char, float>>::value, "!");
static_assert(!is_derived_from_B<int>::value, "!");
static_assert(!is_derived_from_B<B<int,int>>::value, "!");
static_assert(!is_derived_from_B<std::vector<int>>::value, "!");
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/578f9c16276d42fd)

It can be generalized to accept *any base class template*:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <template <typename...> class Base, typename Derived>
    struct is_derived_from_template
    {
        using U = typename std::remove_cv<
                                  typename std::remove_reference<Derived>::type
                                >::type;

        template <typename... Args>
        static auto test(Base<Args...>*)
            -> typename std::integral_constant<bool
                                          , !std::is_same<U, Base<Args...>>::value>;

        static std::false_type test(void*);

        using type = decltype(test(std::declval<U*>()));
    };
}

template <template <typename...> class Base, typename Derived>
using is_derived_from_template
                = typename detail::is_derived_from_template<Base, Derived>::type;
```

*Tests:*

```
static_assert(is_derived_from_template<B, const D<int, int>>::value, "!");
static_assert(!is_derived_from_template<B, int>::value, "!");
static_assert(!is_derived_from_template<B, B<int, int>>::value, "!");
static_assert(!is_derived_from_template<B, std::vector<int>>::value, "!");
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c0e05e8cc53b6e7)

Comment: That looks very much like C++03 style traits. Is there any particular reason for it?

Comment: @dyp, how would the C++11/14 style traits look?

Comment: Slightly shorter, maybe more C++11 style: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04d62c4edab4bc84 cc @Niall

Comment: @dyp Why not simply `using type = decltype(test( std::declval<T*>() ));` and skip `value`?

Comment: @T.C. Because my code is never perfect? ;) (I've refactored Piotr's code) It can be even shorter, see Piotr's edit. You could even remove that class template now.

Comment: Is it possible to create the "factory" by means of using template template parameters?

Comment: [My own version.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9feadc62e7594eb2) But I think direct using of `decltype` is more efficient in sense of compile-time performance.

Comment: `template <typename, typename = void, typename = void > struct B {};` has passed tests too, therefore better name is `is_derived_from_template` (or even `is_derived_from_template_class`, but too verbose).

Comment: Note that in the case of e.g. `struct D : B<int>, B<float>` this will give an ambiguity error rather than `true`.

Comment: @ildjarn: no error, clang returns true, g++ returns false

Comment: So, when `base` and `derived` is the same, we should return `std::true_type` for the uniformity sake (uniformity with STL).

Comment: Are you using a pointer for the parameter to avoid instantiation of `B<Args...>`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: yes, `std::declval<U*>` with dropped cv qualifiers

Comment: @Orient: I added constraint so that `is_derived_from_B<B<int>>` returns false. you can remove this `!std::is_same<U, B<Args...>>::value` if you don't like it

Comment: Why do you remove cv-qualifiers but not references?

Comment: @0x499602D2: for no reason (overlooked), updated now

Comment: @PiotrS. Okay. Well, I don't really know the difference of when to remove cv-qualifiers from a type vs removing references vs decaying the entire type when working with traits. I have to look in on that.

Comment: ...this is wizardry. it lets me achieve the effect of `is_base_of` but on incomplete types, which that can't handle. +1

Comment: In c++20 `using U = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<Derived>::type>::type;` can be replaced by `U = remove_cvref_t<T>;`

Answer (score 4):

I want to propose another solution, that will also work in case of private inheritance. Downsides are that it requires you to modify the base class template and it is base class-specific.

Assuming your base class is `template< typename... Args > class Base`, you need to add a friend function to it:

```
template< /*whatever*/ > class Base {
  //...

  template< typename T >
  friend std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value
  > is_derived_from_Base_impl(T const&); //unevaluated-only
};
```

Then, you can write your trait:

```
template< typename T, typename Enable=void >
struct is_derived_from_Base : std::false_type { };

template< typename T >
struct is_derived_from_Base<T,
  decltype(is_derived_from_Base_impl(std::declval<T const&>()))
> : std::true_type { };
```

This trait won't work in Visual Studio 2015 prior to Update 1, you'll have to write something like:

```
namespace is_derived_from_Base_adl_barrier {
  struct no{}; //anything but void
  no is_derived_from_Base_impl(...);
  template< typename T >
  struct is_derived_from_Base : std::is_void<decltype(
    is_derived_from_Base_impl(std::declval<T const&>());
  )> { };
}
using is_derived_from_Base_adl_barrier::is_derived_from_Base;
```

The thing works because argument-name dependent lookup will find the friend function despite the private inheritance, and the friend function (or functions, if multiple are found) will then check `is_base_of` on an actual specialization.

Comment: I have been searching for the solution of this problem for past 3 hours. It is brilliant and I envy to people who have knowledge to construct such things. Although I create custom type traits regularly I would never come up with solution to this. You have all my respect.