# Technique to distinguish between ordinary template parameters and template template parameters using SFINAE resolution

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, type-traits

The question inspired by recently arised [question about extended `std::is_base_of` type trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845536/).

Is there any technique, which allows us to distinguish between ordinary template parameter and template template parameter in *modern* C++ or its extensions (say, `-std=gnu++1z` **clang++**/**g++**)?

```
namespace details
{

template< /* ??? */ base >
struct is_derived_from;

template< typaneme base >
struct is_derived_from< base >
{
    static std::true_type test(base *);
    static std::false_type test(void *);
};

template< template< typename ...formal > base >
struct is_derived_from< /* ??? */ >
{
    template< typename ...actual > // actual parameters must be here!
    static std::true_type test(base< actual... > *);
    static std::false_type test(void *);
};

} // namespace details

template< typename derived, /* ??? */ base >
using is_derived_from = decltype(details::is_derived_from< /* ? base< ? > */ >::test(std::declval< typename std::remove_cv< derived >::type * >()));
```

In positive case it allows us to make some of useful type traits much more powerfull (for example, STL's `std::is_base_of`).

I think it requires a language feature as a "generalized typenames", isn't it?

Comment: You can't overload class templates. You can use overloading `constexpr` function templates, though, I think.

Comment: @T.C. Are there a fundamental differences between them which we can exploit?

Comment: @T.C. You don't need `constexpr`, it suffices to do overload resolution inside `decltype` with no evaluation.

Comment: @Potatoswatter But if you want to be able to do both `foo<Template, Derived>` and `foo<BaseClass, Derived>` and to use the result at compile time, then you need to use a pair of `constexpr` functions, no?

Comment: @T.C. As long as there's overload resolution, you can replace `constexpr int foo() { return 1; }` with `std::integral_constant< int, 1 > foo(); // no definition`. Not to make a judgment about which is better, you just don't *need* `constexpr` :P . The latter may be more portable though.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Sure, you can make `foo` non-`constexpr` and require people to write `decltype(foo<std::vector, bar>())` or `decltype(foo<std::vector<double>, bar>())` every time they use it. I don't think it's very good interface design, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be only one set of template parameters for class templates, but you can use overloading `constexpr` function templates instead that dispatches to the appropriate class template. Take the `is_derived_from` trait in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845536/), with an extra SFINAE parameter so that you don't get a hard error when `B` is an inaccessible or ambiguous base:

```
#include <type_traits>
namespace detail
{
    template <template <class...> class B, typename Derived>
    struct is_derived_from
    {
        using U = typename std::remove_cv<Derived>::type;

        template <typename... Args, 
                  typename = std::enable_if_t<
                             std::is_convertible<U*, Base<Args...>*>::value>>
        static auto test(B<Args...>*)
            -> typename std::integral_constant<bool
                                           , !std::is_same<U, B<Args...>>::value>;

        static std::false_type test(void*);

        using type = decltype(test(std::declval<U*>()));
    };

    using std::is_base_of; // may want to use is_convertible instead to match
                           // the semantics of is_derived_from
}

template <template <class...> class B, typename Derived>
constexpr bool my_is_base_of() { return detail::is_derived_from<B, Derived>::type::value; }

template <class B, typename Derived>
constexpr bool my_is_base_of() { return detail::is_base_of<B,Derived>::value; }

struct B {};
struct D : B {};

template<class ...>
struct B2 {}; 
struct D2 : B2<int, double> { };

int main() {
  static_assert(my_is_base_of<B2, D2>(), "Oops");
  static_assert(my_is_base_of<B, D>(), "Oops");
  static_assert(my_is_base_of<B2<int, double>, D2>(), "Oops");
  static_assert(!my_is_base_of<B, D2>(), "Oops");
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21794e739adaa9d3).

Comment: `struct BB : B< struct X >, B< struct Y > {};` not causes hard error on **clang++**.

Comment: @Orient That's interesting - but not quite what I meant when I was talking about ambiguous bases.

Comment: Maybe this is the case due to [new memory model](http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-18/episode-ten-when-size-does-matter).

Comment: @Orient No, this is [clang bug 16068](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16068) (and [18834](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18834)). (And what does the memory model has to do with anything?)

Comment: Maybe this is not the bug: maybe parameter should be sliced to the first occurrence of matched base class?

Comment: @Orient No, it is a bug. [temp.deduct.call]/p5 - deduction should fail and it should fall back to the `void *` overload.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Is there any technique, which allows us to distinct between ordinary template parameter and template template parameter in modern C++ or its extensions (say, `-std=gnu++1z` clang++/g++)?

Seems to me like you need something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_template_template : public std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T1, template <typename T> class T2>
struct is_template_template<T2<T1>> : std::true_type
{
};
```

**Example Program**

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct is_template_template : public std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T1, template <typename T> class T2>
struct is_template_template<T2<T1>> : std::true_type
{
};

template <typename T> struct A {};
struct B {};

int main()
{
   std::cout << std::boolalpha;
   std::cout << is_template_template<A<int>>::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << is_template_template<B>::value << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: You misunderstood my questions, but I am the guilty of the situation (due to my poor knowlege of English).

Comment: Please provide an example of how to use your construction in real life. A type trait should be able to identify some meaningfull non-trivial property of the template parameter(s) provided.

Comment: Actual parameter cannot be the `template template`. We can't provide `is_template_template< A >::value`, i.e. can't check whether the identifier is the name of template class.