# Type trait to check whether some type is derived from a class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-traits, c++17

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
template<class A, class B>
class c {};

template<class D>
class e
    : public c<e<D>, /* some type depending on D */>
{ }
```

Given a type `F`, how can I check whether there is some type `B` such that `F` is derived from `c<F, B>`?

Example: For `F = e<D>` there is some type `B` depending on `D` such that `F` is derived from `c<F, B>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trait to check if some specialization of template class is base class of specific class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845536/trait-to-check-if-some-specialization-of-template-class-is-base-class-of-specifi)

Comment: If you are the author if `c`, you can make your life much easier if you derive `c` from a non-template base class `class foo{ }` and then check whether `F` is derived from `foo` using plain `std::is_base_of`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yes, I know and meanwhile I've decided to use such a `e_tag` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer focuses on the question;

> Given a type `F`, how can I check whether there is some type `B` such that `F` is derived from `c<F, B>`?

And the comment for clarity;

> The trait should check if `F` is derived from `c<F, B>` for some `B` (and it's not important what `B` is).

Two `constexpr` functions can be used to "attract" and differentiate the base `c<F, B>` away from other types. **Function templates are favoured because they are able to [deduce types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)** (this would be required to satisfy the requirement *some `B`*). Something of the form as follows...

```
template <typename F, typename B>
constexpr bool check_base(C<F, B> &&) { return true; }

template <typename F>
constexpr bool check_base(...) { return false; }
```

The following sample, with improved usage scenarios, illustrates the basic workings;

```
#include <utility>
template <typename A, typename B>
struct C {};

template <typename F, typename B>
constexpr std::true_type check_base_(C<F, B>&&) { return {}; }

template <typename F>
constexpr std::false_type check_base_(...) { return {}; }

template <typename T>
using check_base = decltype(check_base_<T>(std::declval<T>()));

template <typename D>
struct E : C<E<D>, D> {};
struct FailF {};

int main()
{
    static_assert(check_base<E<int>>());
    static_assert(!check_base<FailF>());
}
```

[See the demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c79b429d5377753).

If we remove the `constexpr`, we can also remove the unneeded inline definitions of the `check_base_` functions.

*Note:* the solutions assumes/asserts an accessible base class (i.e. not `private` or `protected`). If the base class is `private`, the code above would fail to compile, with an accessibility error. The code below will not fail, the SFINAE is done to allow the compilation to continue.

[Online demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff43b1276cad6bb7).

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
template <typename A, typename B>
struct C {};

template <typename F, typename B>
std::true_type check_base_(C<F, B>&&, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<F, C<F,B>>::value>::type* = nullptr);

template <typename F>
std::false_type check_base_(...);

template <typename T>
using check_base = decltype(check_base_<T>(std::declval<T>()));

template <typename D>
struct Example : C<Example<D>, D> {};
struct CtorTest : C<CtorTest, int> { CtorTest(int, int) {} };
struct PrivateBase : private C<PrivateBase, double> {};
struct FailTest {};

int main()
{
    static_assert(check_base<Example<int>>(), "fail...");
    static_assert(check_base<CtorTest>::value, "fail...");
    static_assert(!check_base<PrivateBase>(), "fail...");
    static_assert(!check_base<FailTest>(), "fail...");
}
```

Comment: It should neither be fixed nor be an argument. That's the whole point of the quesiton. The treat should check if `F` is derived from `c<F, B>` for *some* `B` (and it's not important what `B` is).

Comment: You should edit that into the question. As it stands the question contains references to D and B derivations and a class e that do not seem relevant, thus clouding the question.

Comment: I've made that clear in the question, cause I stated that the treat should check if there *exists* some type ...

Comment: @0xbadf00d : "*I've made that clear in the question*" That is certainly subjective. Your question looks like a hot mess to me anyway.

Comment: @ildjarn How could I be any clearer? I've ask for a type treat with type parameter `F` that checks the existence of a type `B` such that `F` is derived from `c<F, B>`. In terms of predicate logic, that's perfectly clear.

Comment: I would make `check_base` return `true_type` and `false_type`, strip the body, then use a `template<T>using check_base=decltype(blah);`.  As written, the code above copies a `C<F,B>` via slicing.

Comment: @Yakk - I get warnings on unimplemented functions that way... The slice shouldn't be a problem. It is is a `constexpr` required for compile time checks. I left it like to minimise code over the value categories, but it could be overloaded more for `const`, `&&etc.

Comment: @Niall write a noisy ctor in the sliced class, and watch your code fail to be constexpr?  `constexpr` doesn't mean "evaluate at compile time even if I cannot usually".

Comment: @Yakk, something like this? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c79b429d5377753. I like now that it doesn't need a default constructor as well.

Comment: @Yakk, I note it works without the `constexpr` as well... removes the "inline warning". Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @0xbadf00d. I've made several improvement in the listed code and remove the `constexpr` issues... I am happier with the results.

Comment: @Niall Do `return {};` instead of `return true_type;`.  No need to repeat yourself!

Comment: @Yakk, true that... I'll admit, I favour the form with no `constexpr` in it at all - it solves a number of niggly things I didn't like in the original code. I appreciate your help.

Comment: This fails to detect `private` inheritance.

Comment: @Johannes. Yes. From the OP example, I'm not sure if the OP needs it. I'll look again when I get a chance, but I'm battling to get away from the *some B* that is requested, hence needs to be deduced.

Comment: @Johannes, any ideas to enable private inheritance?

Comment: @Niall if I'm not mistaken, it really causes a compiler error, rather than saying that it does or does not derive. To prevent a compiler error, you could perhaps add some SFINAE by trying to `static_cast` from the argument type to the base. Private inheritance will cause an SFINAE failure.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb. I've added some logic (a `is_convertible`) to allow for a SFINAE failure over the compilation error for the private base. It does mean that the base needs to be public. I'd like to get a working solution for the private bases as well, I just can't work around the requirement to deduce the base class as well as the private accessibility... another problem for another day.

Comment: @0xbadf00d. I've added some logic (a `is_convertible`) to allow for a SFINAE failure over the compilation error for the `private` base. It does mean that the base needs to be `public` - but the compilation errors are now taken care of.