# How to handle two levels template?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a two levels template:

types

```
class Type{};
class TypeExt:public Type{};
```

1, Fist level:

```
//the type must be an inheritance of Type
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Type, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
class FirstLevel{};

class FirstLevelSpecialization_1:public FirstLevel<Type>{};
class FirstLevelSpecialization_2:public FirstLevel<TypeExt>{};
```

2, Second Level

```
//the type must be an inheritance of FirstLevel
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<FirstLevel, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
class SecondLevel{};

class SecondLevelSpecialization: public SecondLevel<FirstLevelSpecialization_1>{};
```

The last line will give an error:

```
Invalid template arguments
```

I know how to solve this problem in Java,questions are:

```
1,Is this problem solvable in C++?
2,If yes,would you please give some tips to solve it?
```

Comment: Sound like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390605/doing-a-static-assert-that-a-template-type-is-another-template) is what you want.

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845536/trait-to-check-if-some-specialization-of-template-class-is-base-class-of-specifi).