# Writing a type trait for detecting Matrix Expressions in Eigen

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, eigen, type-traits

I am trying (and failing) to write a type trait that detects Eigen expressions. In other words, I'd like to be able to detect things like `A * A + B` etc. where `A` and `B` are `Eigen` matrices/vectors. Currently I'm doing this:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_matrix_expression : std::false_type
{
};

template<typename Derived> // specialization
struct is_matrix_expression<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>> :
        std::true_type
{
};
```

Note that `Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>` is a (template) base for all possible Eigen expressions (such as `decltype(A * A + B)` etc). However, the general template is being picked out, as it is a better match for something like `decltype(A * A + B)`, and not the `MatrixBase<Derived>` specialization.

How can I somehow enforce the specialization to be picked out? Or, in other words, enable the specialization for all possible children of `Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>`? I played a bit with SFINAE on `std::is_base_of`, but that requires an explicit type and not a template where the type of the expression (in this case `Derived`) is not known in advance.

Equivalently, how can I detect whether a type `X` is a child of `Base<T>`, for some type `T`?

Comment: Drop that `typename`. Do you write `typename std::template vector<int>`?

Comment: Is [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12182195/27678) helpful?

Comment: I think your issue is that `decltype(A * A + B)` isn't `MatrixBase<T>`... it's going to be like `CwiseBinaryOp<X,Y,Z>` right?

Comment: @Barry Yes, which is a child of `MatrixBase<...>`.

Comment: @T.C., sorry, typo, corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This detects if something inherits from `bob_template<T>`:

```
template<class T>
struct bob_template {};

template<class T>
constexpr std::true_type is_bob_f( bob_template<T> const& ) { return {}; }

namespace details {
    template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
    struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
    template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
    struct can_apply<Z, std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;

template<class T>
using is_bob_r = decltype( is_bob_f( std::declval<T const&>() ) );

template<class T>
using is_bob = can_apply< is_bob_r, T >;
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4bd72d5b156a07b).

C++20 has `is_detected` which is similar to `can_apply` above.

`std::void_t` is C++14, but easy to write in C++11.

To read the above in english:

`is_bob<T>` is true if and only if you can invoke `is_bob_r<T>`.

`is_bob_r` can be invoked if `is_bob_f( T const& )` is a valid call.

`is_bob_f` has an overload for `is_bob_f( bob_template<T> const& )` only.

`can_apply<Z, T>` is (derived from) `true_type` if `Z<T>` is valid, and (derived from) `false_type` otherwise.

So `is_bob<T>` is true if and only if `T` can be deduced into `bob_template<U>` for some `U`.  Which basically means `bob_template<U>` is a (public) base class of `T`.

Comment: That's very nice and generic!

Answer (score 5):

Something like this here should do:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct is_matrix_expression
 : std::is_base_of<Eigen::MatrixBase<std::decay_t<Derived> >, std::decay_t<Derived> >
{};
```

It prints true for the following piece of code:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A, B;
std::cout<< is_matrix_expression <decltype(A*A + B)>::value <<std::endl;   //true
std::cout<< is_matrix_expression <int>::value <<std::endl;                 //false
```

Idea is that here you know what the base class looks like: namely, for `SomeMatrixXpr`, it will be `MatrixBase<SomeMatrixXpr>` according to the [Eigen class hierarchy](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicClassHierarchy.html). This is in contrast to @Yakk's approach, which works for any type of Base classes (even those not related by CRTP).

Comment: This does it too!

Comment: @vsoftco: thanks, I made an edit [why](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicClassHierarchy.html)

Comment: You are missing a `typename` I think?  But really you should just shave the `::type` off the end of `is_base_of`; inheriting is good enough.

Comment: @Yakk: yes, you're right ... tested it on MSVC which is very sloppy with the `typename`s.

Comment: @Yakk Where is the `typename` missing? Don't see anything wrong (not even in the edits), `decay_t` doesn't need `typename` (as opposed with `decay<>::type`, does it?

Comment: @vsoftco `std::is_base_of< blah >::type` needed it.  It was a dependent type.  As I pointed out, instead of adding `typename` just remove `::type`, because that works just as well.

Comment: @Yakk Ah ok, sure, but there's no need for it ;) Thanks! Funny enough, gcc accepts the code without `typename` (if I use `is_base_of<>::type`), I'm trying to figure out why, as it shouldn't.

Comment: @Yakk Found it. There's no need for `typename` in the class derived parameter list, as every name written in a derived class's base-specifier-list is already treated as a type-name.